Appscript REST Api slowness
I am calling the following appscript function using google.script.run from my mobile application.
Code
function addOrUpdateEntry(response) {
      
     let sheetName = "X";
    var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock(); //Use Document Lock as we can also be editting these fields. 
    var lockTimeoutMS = 5000; // 5,000 ms = 5 seconds

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(getSpreadsheetId())
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
     
    var data = JSON.parse(response);

    var a= data.a;
    var b= data.b;
    var c= data.c;
    var d= data.d;
    var f= data.f;
    var username = data.username;
    var todayDateDDMMYYYY = GetCurrentDateAsDDMMYYYY();
    var g= data.g;

    if (g< 0) {
        g= g* -1; //Make it positive.
    }

    if (lock) {
        var success = lock.tryLock(lockTimeoutMS);
        if (!success) {
            throw new Error("Unable to attain lock.");
        }
    }

    var dataRange;
    var values;

    try {
      
        dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
        values = dataRange.getValues();
        var result = []

        /**
         * find list of rows to update
         */
        for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["a"]] == a) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["b"]] == b) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["c"]] == c) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["d"]] == d)) {
                
                result.push(i);
            }
        }

        let newData = [a, b, c, d, e, g, username, todayDateDDMMYYYY];

        if (result.length > 0) {
          /**
           * update rows with new data
          */
            for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                sheet.getRange(result[j] + 1, 1, 1, newData.length).setValues([newData]);
            }
        } else {
          /**
           * update rows with new data
           */
            sheet.appendRow(newData);
        }
        
        return JSON.stringify(true);

    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    finally {
        if (lock) {
            lock.releaseLock();
        }
    }
}

The function takes 2-3 seconds to execute for a sheet with 1000 rows. In the client app, it takes 5-6 seconds to receive the REST API result using Retrofit. Upon checking the function, it seems that most of the time is taken by the SpreadsheetApp.openById(getSpreadsheetId()) and sheet.getDataRange().getValues() methods.
I'm looking for a way to speed things up.

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your current issue, in your showing script, I thought that the loop using setValues might be a high cost. So, how about the following modification?
From:
        var result = []

        /**
         * find list of rows to update
         */
        for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["a"]] == a) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["b"]] == b) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["c"]] == c) &&
                (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["d"]] == d)) {
                
                result.push(i);
            }
        }

        let newData = [a, b, c, d, e, g, username, todayDateDDMMYYYY];

        if (result.length > 0) {
          /**
           * update rows with new data
          */
            for (let j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
                sheet.getRange(result[j] + 1, 1, 1, newData.length).setValues([newData]);
            }
        } else {
          /**
           * update rows with new data
           */
            sheet.appendRow(newData);
        }

To:
let newData = [a, b, c, d, e, g, username, todayDateDDMMYYYY];
var obj = { result: [], temp: [] };
for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
  if (
    (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["a"]] == a) &&
    (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["b"]] == b) &&
    (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["c"]] == c) &&
    (values[i][TableToColumnLookup[sheetName]["d"]] == d)) {
    obj.result.push(newData);
    obj.temp.push(i);
  } else {
    obj.result.push(values[i]);
  }
}
if (obj.temp.length > 0) {
  const maxLen = Math.max(...obj.result.map((r) => r.length));
  const v = obj.result.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v);
} else {
  sheet.appendRow(newData);
}


By this modification, the created values are put into the sheet by one request.


There is no way to speedup SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId). Also please bear in mind that the execution time of this command might vary to factors that are unrelated to your account and spreadsheet. If the response time is critical, consider to use the Sheets API instead of Google Apps Script or even to use another source for the data required by your mobile app.
The above because, according to official docs (reference pending), Apps Script is inteded to be rapid development platform rather than a high performance at runtime platform.
Regarding SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange().getValues() this might be "slow" due to spreadsheet formulas and data conversion from data types used in Google Sheets to JavaScript data types.
One workaround might be to use SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues() as it will return strings for all cells. Another workaround might be to periodically make a copy of the sheet values to a different spreadsheet to prevent having the original spreadsheet to recalculate formulas on each call from your mobile app.
